# Force jetty to display error details

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am currently trying to learn how to use maven and jetty. But i am having a problem my jersey page is throwing an error 500, the error it self is not my problem. 
But i would like jetty to display the full error message for me instead of just

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /hello. Reason:

    Internal Server Error
```

How can i get jetty to display the full error details when it encounter an error like this?
Here is my pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <properties>
        <docker.imageName>${artifactId}</docker.imageName>
        <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jersey.version>2.5</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycode</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mycode</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <!-- <jettyConfig>jetty.xml</jettyConfig> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>bash-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-ts-20141204</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <script>
                                rsync -a --delete ${project.basedir}/docker/ ${project.build.directory}/docker
                                cp -p ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war ${project.build.directory}/docker/root.war
                                find ${project.build.directory}/docker | xargs touch -t 197409101630.00
                                docker build -f DockerfileBase -t mysite/jettybase ${project.build.directory}/docker
                                docker build -t mysite/${docker.imageName} ${project.build.directory}/docker
                            </script>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <script>
                                <!--docker push ${docker.imageName}-->
                                echo '123'
                            </script>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core" -->
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any of your servlets or filters does a response.sendError(500), that's what you'll get. no stacktrace.

If you have no ErrorHandler on the server defined, that is also what you will get.

If you have an ErrorHandler, then either it had .setShowStacks(false) called, or there simply wasn't a stacktrace to show.

If the output says `Powered by Jetty://`, then it was produced by something in Jetty, if not, then its not a Jetty component producing that error page.

Lastly, you can also just setup your own error handing in your `WEB-INF/web.xml` for your webapp, use the documentation for help (such as what attributes to use to get the appropriate stacktrace for you out of the request object)

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/custom-error-pages.html